# How can I output the difference between 2 files?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, output

My file consists of the the following; roughly:

```
username:username:username:username:username
```

The above line continues to about 600 characters.

I use the `awk` command in order to use it as an argument in a API/HTTP request sent from the command line.

I'm using my script to get a list of user accounts 'following' me, and every 24 hours or so, comparing the original list on my hard disk to the newly outputted username list (and **echo'ing out who is no longer following me**.
I will have to encapsulate my logic into a loop using bash.. testing each username.

My current script:

```
user=$(awk -F: '{ print $1 }' FILE)  # Grab $User to use as an argument.  
following=$(exec CURRENT_FOLLOWERS) # Outputs the new file

echo "X amount of users are following you on 78B066B87AF16A412556458AC85EFEF66155"  

          SAVE CURRENT FOLLOWERS TO NEW A FILE.  


if [[ DIFFERENCE IS DETECTED ]] ; then    

          echo -ne "$User NO LONGER FOLLOWING YOU\r"

   else echo -ne "This user is following you still.\r"
fi
```

My question is;
**How can I output the difference between 2 files?**

Comment: You know about `diff` , right?

Comment: @schaiba Thank you. Just came across that on another forum, works great. I hadn't stumbled upon it before that. I hope this answer is useful for future queries by other members.

Comment: @schaiba may as well make an answer of it. Make sure to deal with diff working on _lines_ not fields though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The utility you're looking for is `diff`. Take a peek at the manual for details.

Comment: *[Sometimes people run diff with the new file first instead of second. This creates a diff that is “reversed”.](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Reversed-Patches.html)*   Better idea: don't do that.  Put the new file second.

Answer (score 18):

Given two files containing unsorted lists of users, e.g.

```
In file1:
    userD
    user3
    userA
    user1
    userB
```

and

```
In file2:
    user3
    userB
    userX
    user1
```

then to get a simple list of the users in `file1` but not in `file2`, you can do

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
userA
userD
```

and similarly to get the users in `file2` but not in `file1`

```
$ comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
userX
```

If the list files are already sorted, these can be simplified to `comm -23 file1 file2` and `comm -13 file1 file2` respectively.

Comment: Is it possible to use `comm` without sorting? My text file has values like `1`, `2`, `01`, `02`, `0000`, `0001`, `0002`, etc. Using `sort` will de-sort the order...

Comment: `comm -23 file1 file2` works for me ! It is in my case on files list (pictures and thumb) and I run `comm -23 img_list thumb_list > img-ok_th-nok` and I have thumb list I should generate

Answer (score 7):

The best command to view the difference in the files content would be

```
vim -d file1 file2
```

Answer (score 3):

`diff [options] from-file to-file`

`diff` compares the contents of the two files from-file and to-file.You can specify the `-i` option that ignores changes in case; consider upper- and lower-case letters equivalent.

For more information you can refer this link : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm or you can have a look at the manual page.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the same windows like `fc` command in Unix and Linux i.e. `diff <file_new> <file_old>` command.

Line with `+++` or `---` in front of them have changed and one with no `+'s` and `-'s` haven't changed

Lines with `-` sign are removed from the new file however they existed in old version

Lines with `+` sign are added from in new file however they didn't existed in old version of the file

**Linux notation**

Linux uses `>`  and `<`

`>` means the line from old file 
`<` means the line from new file that is changed in old file

Answer (score 0):

Go for [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) for Showing differences between two,
three or four versions of the same file.