# Find ONLY the difference (extra) between two files in unix

Tags: shell-script, diff

I have 2 files. names1.txt and names2.txt.

I need to know that which names are present in names1.txt but are missing in names2.txt.
Then I need to store them in another file missing_names.txt.

Diff command gives the difference but it also prints lot many information. Also, I do not want to know the names which are in names2.txt but are missing in names1.txt.
So its like (names1.txt - names2.txt) operation.

Comment: Read `man comm`.

Comment: Answered here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144623/how-can-i-output-the-difference-between-2-files - downvoted because the question shows no intention of using a search engine before posting .

Comment: can you please post sample content of your files, and expected behavior ?

Comment: That question is different to what I asked. That question is more generalized. Mine is more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff <(sort -u names2.txt) <(sort -u names1.txt) | 
  sed -n -e 's/^> //p' > missing_names.txt
```

or

```
diff <(sort -u names1.txt) <(sort -u names2.txt) | 
    sed -n -e 's/^< //p' > missing_names.txt
```

Either of those will give you ONLY the names that are in names1 but not names2.

`diff` (without any output-format options like `-u`) prints additions prefixed with `>` (> followed by a space) and deletions prefixed by `<` (< followed by a space).  The `sed` scripts strip those from the beginning of the line if they're there and only prints modified (i.e. matching) lines.

Comment: Savior. Thanks. Works good for now. Will do more analysis and report back.

Comment: FYI, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296643/i-want-to-compare-2-files-in-aix-and-print-the-difference-in-numbers for a similar question I answered last night.

Comment: The solution is not that accurate. If the line in one file is present in another  file as well but at some other position then it is coming in the result. This should not happen. Sorting is working but sorting is combining few of the line.

Comment: you're right about accuracy, so i edited my answer to `sort -u` the input files....but what do you mean by "sorting is combining few of the line"?  `sort` doesn't combine lines.  it sorts its input, and that's all it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat name_1.txt | while read line
do
  grep -q "$line" name_2.txt
  if [ "$?" -gt "0" ]; then
     echo "$line" >> name_3.txt
  fi
done
```

**NOTE:** Assuming `name_1.txt` and `name_2.txt` contains only names.

Comment: @rahul UUOC is only reason enough for making a comment, not for editing someone else's answer.

Comment: The output is - grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: `-q` is used for silent. You can use above code snipped by removing `-q` as well.

Comment: If your grep doesn't have `-q` for quiet (no output), use `grep "$line" name_2.txt > /dev/null`.  Also, the `grep` and the `if` lines can be combined into `if ! grep -q "$line" name_2.txt ; then`.  Or get rid of the `if` entirely and use `||`:   `grep -q "$line" name_2.txt || echo "$line" >> name_3.txt`